# Add back arrow in fragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a framelayout in MainActivity and I've attached TabFragment fragment to the activity. The TabFragment has TabLayout as well as Navigation Drawer. I used this link's recommended answer to style toolbar in TabFragment. But when I use `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in a NewFragment(it opens on button click from one of the tab) the app crashes with NullPointerException. I want the back arrow without using any drawable icon. Thanks for any help in this regard.

```html
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.sam.pagersliding, PID: 7652
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at com.sam.pagersliding.NewFragment.onCreate(NewFragment.java:27)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1951)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```js
public class NewFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newfrag, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

```css
public class TabFragment extends Fragment{

    Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfrag, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_one) {
                    NavOne nav1 = new NavOne();
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(nav1);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_two) {
                    NavTwo nav2 = new NavTwo();
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment(nav2);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);

                }

                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction myFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Attach main fragment to activity
        if (findViewById(R.id.containerView) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            myFragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            myFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();
        }



    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
    }



}
```

Comment: "The app crashes" -- Please [edit] your question with the logcat, then

Comment: Added Logcat. Its in the same line ` ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` @cricket_007

Comment: Why are you trying to set the Activity's Toolbar from the Fragment? That seems like a poor design. You can toggle the Up arrow whenever you use the FragmentTransaction in the Activity code.

Comment: Can you show me how to toggle it ? Please note that I've:
`<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` and 
        `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in styles.xml @cricket_007

Comment: XML doesn't matter. `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in the **Activity** instead of the **Fragment** is all I said

Comment: I added `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in onCreate of MainActivity but now the app crashes on opening. @cricket_007

Comment: I can't count the line numbers of your code, but I assume you now have a different error or it is on a different line. You are welcome to read about [reading the Logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to fix your errors, or more generally, [using the stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). Both are valuable tools that you can use to debug and solve most simple errors such as a NullPointerException

Comment: Its in the same line `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` but now its in activity. Logically when windowActionBar is false in styles then it should not support Actionbar at all in activity. @cricket_007

Comment: Ah! I think you are missing `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in the onCreate of the Activity. Yeah, your Toolbar is null otherwise if you use the NoActionBar themes

Comment: And your Toolbar (and the following views) should ideally be in the Activity's layout file, not the Fragment

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your last suggestion `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` worked for me. I removed the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and included the toolbar from activity. @cricket_007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of getting the toolbar in your fragment from layout, try to reference it from your MainActivity:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and then use in the fragment:

```
     ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: "try to reference it from your MainActivity" seems to conflict with "then in the Fragment"

Comment: There is a different problem with this solution. If I want menu icon in the Navigation fragments then how to do it? Bcuz if I use above code, I'm getting same `back arrow` icon and text in each fragment. I can change the text but how to show menu icon ?

Comment: You can add a reference to the toolbar in each fragment through Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getCustomView(); so then you can change the icon with setIcon method

Comment: Add what? I've 2 fragments in Navigation Drawer and I want menu icon in both fragments but its showing back arrow icon in both.

Comment: Not looking to use icon drawables. Any other idea to get menu icon in fragment?

Comment: I'm sorry I think I have misunderstood your problem. As you have used setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in one fragment, to show again the menu icon in other fragments you can use the same method with false parameter

Answer (score 3):

The below two feature should be enabled

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

along with setting the back button

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I added your recommendation. Its showing error when adding `onCreateOptionsMenu` in fragment so didn't used it. And the app still crashes on clicking the button in one of the tabs of TabLayout. @Stallion

Answer (score -1):

remove this line

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

from `onActivityCreated`

try to use it on resume

```
((AppCompatActivity)getView().getContext())getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method `getActivity()` and `getSupportActionBar()` @sush